# Apple Pay: How can I get `shippingAddress` before show the order information?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, applepay, applepayjs

I'm using Apple Pay integration with Stripe and I need to get the `shippingAddress` from Apple Pay before shown the order information because I need to calculate taxes and shipment cost based on the address.

Currently, I can get the shipmentAddress but after show the window with the information.

I'm sending this payload:

```
    var paymentRequest = {
      requiredShippingContactFields: ['postalAddress','email', 'phone'],
      countryCode: 'US',
      currencyCode: 'USD',
      lineItems: this.buildLineItems(lineItems),
      total: this.buildTotal(lineItems)
    };
```

There's a way to get the shipment information before show the window or update the window based on the information that I get?

Source:

- https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay/web/v2
- https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay/web/v2/custom

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Checkout or Elements (with the Payment Request Button)?

Comment: @thmsdnnr I'm following this guide https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay/web/v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the shipment information you need to listen for `onshippingcontactselected`

```
session.onshippingcontactselected = (event) => {
  // You can do work asynchronously here; just call
  // session.completeShippingMethodSelection when you're done.
}
```

Documentation

https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#payment-request-on

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/applepaysession/1778009-onshippingcontactselected?language=javascript